# How to logout gmail using selenium script?

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am writing selenium script for Gmail login and logout functionality. I am able to successfully login using below code.

```
//Open gmail
         driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");

         // Enter userd id
         WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));
         element.sendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");

         //wait 5 secs for  userid to be entered
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

         //Enter Password
         WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd"));
         element1.sendKeys("Password");

         //Submit button
         element.submit();
```

But i could not write a script to logout. Could yu please provide me script for logout?

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you have a specific need to, why are you trying to automate through Gmail with Selenium? They have extensive set of API's that allow you to login/read emails/send emails all without a browser.

Comment: To expand on what @Arran said: unless you have specific permission to run automation against someone else's server, that is a good way to get your IP blacklisted.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very bad idea trying to automate Gmail. First of all, it is against Google's policy and when you sign up for Gmail, you accepted terms and conditions that you won't automate. Having said that there are many efficient ways to connect to your Gmail account. One of the approaches is to use IMAP client like IMAP4. Using this, you can connect to your Gmail, go through your inbox, delete messages,sign out etc. By doing this, you don't have to worry about automating UI portion. Also, Google changes its UI frequently just to stop people from automating it, so if you automate Gmail UI, then it might work today but it won't work after a couple of days.
Go through this link and you should be able to implement IMAP4 in your tests within few minutes:
http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/discussions/269058

Comment: I wanted to use gmail to learn about Selenium.  They're usually pretty tolerant, but...  What would be a good alternate website to use, perhaps?

Comment: @Thufir Try http://www.w3schools.com/ They have many functional examples of different tech, and you can try your automation against that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
driver.findElement(By.className("gb_Ta")).click(); // To click the flyout menu
driver.findElement(By.className("gb_71")).click(); // To click the sign out button
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/a")).click();

```
    // click on actual logout button step 2
    driver.findElement(By.id("gb_71")).click();

    //closing the webdriver window after successful completion of the test
    driver.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,50);
WebElement logout=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.gb_4.gbii"));
logout.click();
WebElement signout=driver.findElement(By.id("gb_71"));
signout.click();
```

Comment: You should add commentary discussing why this is an answer.  Explain why it works.

Answer (score 0):

After login to gmail,  Try this code to logout:-

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='gb_7 gbii']")).click();     driver.findElement(By.id("gb_71")).click();

Answer (score 0):

```
use xpath 

// Click on the image icon present in the top right navigational Bar
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='gb_1 gb_3a gb_nc gb_e']/div/a")).click();
//Click on 'Logout' Button
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gb_71']")).click();
//Close the browser.
driver.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

use cssSelector

```
//Click on the profile image present in the right top corner
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.gb_3a.gbii")).click();
//Click on 'Sign Out' button
driver.findElement(By.id("gb_71")).click();  //Close the browser
window driver.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

use `cssselector`:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.gb_8a.gbii")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("gb_71")).click();
```

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work - you can also add code as well as the comments in the code itself 
- in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question. This is especially important for an older question and the questions that already have answers.

Comment: The reason it works is the first driver.findElement.click() clicks on the user's profile icon (in the upper right of the gmail window) which causes a dropdown box to open with the signout link in it. The signout link has the id gb_71. You're welcome.Also, Arran's comment is a much better idea, use the API don't automate button clicks. It's likely that a future gmail update will break your script.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code for sign out the gmail using the selenium webdriver. It's working for me**

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".gb_b.gb_db.gb_R")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);// Click on the image icon present in the top
```

right navigational Bar

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".gb_Fa.gb_Pe.gb_We.gb_wb")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000); //Signout button
```